# No response when try test nodejs express4 route with chai-http

Tags: node.js, typescript, chai, chai-http

I try run test for nodejs express4 routes and can't get response, if try run app and perform native (POstMan) test - work like a sharm).

**APP.ts**

```
import express = require('express');
import expressValidator = require('express-validator');
import bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(expressValidator())

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).send({message: "Hello"}));

app.route("/book")
    .get((req,res)=>{console.log(req.path);return res.status(200)})
    .post((req,res)=>{return res.status(

//Run
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port '+ 3000)
})

export = app;
```

**test.ts**

```
import chai = require('chai');
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
import mocha = require('mocha');

let server = require('../dist/app');
let expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('/GET', () => {
      it('it should not GET a book without pages field', (done) => {
                        chai.request(server)
                        .get('/book')
                        .end(function(err, res) {
                            expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                            done();                               // <= Call done to signal callback end
                        });
            });
  });
```

As result I get error

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/book` doesn't send any response back to client. That's why your testcase is timing out.

`res.status(200)` only set the http response code to 200, but doesn't send 
any response. You can try `resp.sendStatus(200)`.

Comment: I try `res.status(200).send({})` and this works, thanks!